# Differences between stereotype properties and tagged value?

Tags: uml, papyrus, stereotype

What is the differences between stereotype properties and tagged value in UML? I read about them but I don't know the main differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UML2.x has no tagged values. They are still defined in MOF but are removed for UML. Stereotypes have standard Properties. And those Properties are displayed as Properties of the extended Element (not with curly braces). They *can* be displayed using French quotes but can be any other way.

Stereotypes are a mighty concept to extend any Metaclass with additional Properties, Constraints and Dependencies. They are not comparable to the tagged values other than they are a extension mechanism as well.

A hands-on eclipse tutorial for UML2 stereotypes can be found [here](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/uml2/docs/articles/Introduction_to_UML2_Profiles/article.html). You can scan through it to get an impression on the complexity.

Comment: thank you @Christian for clarification.when can i find the standard properties for each stereotype?

Comment: um, with standard I meant the 'Property' class from UML2. There are no default properties for all Stereotypes - each Profile defines them for each Stereotype introduced in the Profile.

Answer (score 4):

A stereotype in UML is represented using French quotes (e.g. `«User»`), whilst a tagged value is represented using curly brackets (`{something}`). Stereotypes can be attached to any UML element, whist tagged values, since UML 2.0, are actually *stereotype attributes*.

So, you annotate elements with a stereotype, an you can attach tagged value to the stereotype.

Comment: Does this mean there is no difference between tagged value and stereotype property?

Comment: From UML 2.0, yes. It was different in UML 1.x, though. For a longer discussion you can look at [this page](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/profile-diagrams.html#stereotype)

Answer (score 0):

A stereotype cannot be used by itself, but must always be used with one of the meta-classes it extends. Stereotype cannot be extended by another stereotype. And also Stereotype can change the graphical appearance of the extended model element by using attached icon.

tag represents a particular kind of property applicable to one or many kinds of model elements. and Both the tag and the value are usually encoded as strings though UML tool allow to use other data types for values.
For example,
  {author="Joe Smith", deadline=31-March-1997, status=analysis}

Tag values could be shown in attached comment under stereotype name.

Stereotype Computer applied with tag values in comment note